# How to enforce a required field in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am building a cms using elastic search on the back end and my team has decided to use elastic search. I am new to it. I mostly use mongoose with mongodb from previous projects. In mongodb if I wrong assign a field or completely skip a required field mongodb throws an error.

Is there a way to enforce required fields in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 7):

There is not built in functionality, that will allow you to define required/mandatory fields in the mappings. Many will recommend you to do checks on the client side.

However, in Elasticsearch 5.x you have the possibility to do the trick by using Ingest node.

> You can use ingest node to pre-process documents before the actual
>   indexing takes place. This pre-processing happens by an ingest node
>   that intercepts bulk and index requests, applies the transformations,
>   and then passes the documents back to the index or bulk APIs.
>
> To pre-process documents before indexing, you define a pipeline that
>   specifies a series of processors. Each processor transforms the
>   document in some way.

An example, which shows the possibility of using this approach.

```
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "processors": [
      {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "if (ctx.title == null) { throw new Exception('Document does not have the *title* field') }"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_type": "type",
      "_id": "1",
      "_source": {
        "title": "Elasticsearch 101"
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "index",
      "_type": "type",
      "_id": "2",
      "_source": {
        "company": "Elastic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

For more information please take a look here - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/ingest.html

Comment: Is there something new about this in Elasticsearch `7.x` ?