# how to represent required fields in index mapping in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

```
mapping: {
  dynamic: 'strict',
  properties: {
    name: { type: 'text', index: false },
    email: { type: 'keyword' },
    phoneNumber: { type: 'text', index: false },
  },
},
```

How to add the required field for name, email and phone number?

Comment: By required do you mean mandatory fields, similar to not null?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enforce a required field in elastic search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928101/how-to-enforce-a-required-field-in-elastic-search)

Comment: yes @OpsterESNinjaNishant
 as like add-in MongoDB, for example {required: true}